# Enquiry on certain derivatives involving the Big O notation and Laurent series

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ has a Laurent series $g(x)$ around $x=1$, and that $g(x) = 1 + O(h(x))$ near $x=1$. Does it necessarily follow that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (1+O(h(x))$$ ?

Answer (score 0):

No.
$g(x)-1$
may oscillate boundedly
and have its derivative
get large.

For example,
$g(x)
=1+h(x)\sin(\frac1{x-1})
=1+O(h(x))
$.